# Filter a pandas dataframe using values from a dict

Tags: python, pandas

I need to filter a data frame with a dict, constructed with the key being the column name and the value being the value that I want to filter:

```
filter_v = {'A':1, 'B':0, 'C':'This is right'}
# this would be the normal approach
df[(df['A'] == 1) & (df['B'] ==0)& (df['C'] == 'This is right')]
```

But I want to do something on the lines

```
for column, value in filter_v.items():
    df[df[column] == value]
```

but this will filter the data frame several times, one value at a time, and not apply all filters at the same time. Is there a way to do it programmatically?

EDIT: an example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,0,1,1, np.nan], 'B':[1,1,1,0,1], 'C':['right','right','wrong','right', 'right'],'D':[1,2,2,3,4]})
filter_v = {'A':1, 'B':0, 'C':'right'}
df1.loc[df1[filter_v.keys()].isin(filter_v.values()).all(axis=1), :]
```

gives

```
    A   B   C   D
0   1   1   right   1
1   0   1   right   2
3   1   0   right   3
```

but the expected result was

```
    A   B   C   D
3   1   0   right   3
```

only the last one should be selected.

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: A dataframe with only the values that correspond to all the conditions simultaneously.

Comment: There should be an easy-to-use command in pandas for this, for example, something like `df.query_values(filter_v)`.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

IIUC, you should be able to do something like this:

```
>>> df1.loc[(df1[list(filter_v)] == pd.Series(filter_v)).all(axis=1)]
   A  B      C  D
3  1  0  right  3
```

---

This works by making a Series to compare against:

```
>>> pd.Series(filter_v)
A        1
B        0
C    right
dtype: object
```

Selecting the corresponding part of `df1`:

```
>>> df1[list(filter_v)]
    A      C  B
0   1  right  1
1   0  right  1
2   1  wrong  1
3   1  right  0
4 NaN  right  1
```

Finding where they match:

```
>>> df1[list(filter_v)] == pd.Series(filter_v)
       A      B      C
0   True  False   True
1  False  False   True
2   True  False  False
3   True   True   True
4  False  False   True
```

Finding where they *all* match:

```
>>> (df1[list(filter_v)] == pd.Series(filter_v)).all(axis=1)
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool
```

And finally using this to index into df1:

```
>>> df1.loc[(df1[list(filter_v)] == pd.Series(filter_v)).all(axis=1)]
   A  B      C  D
3  1  0  right  3
```

Comment: Nice solution and awesome explanation.

Comment: @DSM how would you check if `df` columns from `dict.keys` contains `str` from `dict.values`??

Comment: The use of list(filter_v) and Series(filter_v) makes this solution cryptic. Why not just use `df1[ filter_v.keys() ] == filter_v.values()` as the inner condition?

Comment: I never new you could mask with a series like that!  This is really a great recipe.  Should be in the cookbook me thinks.

Comment: @PrasadChalasani - I don't think that works.  You need to create a series to cause the `==` operator to produce a mask on the right columns .

Comment: This is amazing.

Comment: A-Mazing, thanks!  If your filter happens to already be in a series `filter_s` : `df.loc[ (df[filter_s.index.values] == filter_s).all(axis=1) ]` .  And if you need to drop conditions from the series... `filter_s = filter_s.drop(['area','power','taste'])`

Answer (score 5):

Abstraction of the above for case of passing array of filter values rather than single value (analogous to pandas.core.series.Series.isin()). Using the same example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,0,1,1, np.nan], 'B':[1,1,1,0,1], 'C':['right','right','wrong','right', 'right'],'D':[1,2,2,3,4]})
filter_v = {'A':[1], 'B':[1,0], 'C':['right']}
##Start with array of all True
ind = [True] * len(df1)

##Loop through filters, updating index
for col, vals in filter_v.items():
    ind = ind & (df1[col].isin(vals))

##Return filtered dataframe
df1[ind]

##Returns

    A   B    C      D
0   1.0 1   right   1
3   1.0 0   right   3
```

Comment: This approach works, even when 'vals' is a list with multiple criteria.

Also, I find it useful that I can use the resulting 'ind' to assign a static value (or values from another column) to specific rows in the original dataframe

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to do it:

```
df.loc[df[filter_v.keys()].isin(filter_v.values()).all(axis=1), :]
```

**UPDATE:**

With values being the same across columns you could then do something like this:

```
# Create your filtering function:

def filter_dict(df, dic):
    return df[df[dic.keys()].apply(
            lambda x: x.equals(pd.Series(dic.values(), index=x.index, name=x.name)), axis=1)]

# Use it on your DataFrame:

filter_dict(df1, filter_v)
```

Which yields:

```
   A  B      C  D
3  1  0  right  3
```

If it something that you do frequently you could go as far as to patch DataFrame for an easy access to this filter:

```
pd.DataFrame.filter_dict_ = filter_dict
```

And then use this filter like this:

```
df1.filter_dict_(filter_v)
```

Which would yield the same result.

**BUT**, it is not the *right* way to do it, clearly.
I would use DSM's approach.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that this is also applying only the last key pair on the dict.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are saying... This approach is simple filter of all columns that are coded as keys in your `filter` dictionary and then filter for all values in rows to match values in dictionary. Perhaps you can illustrate the issue with reproducible example?

Answer (score 4):

For python2, that's OK in @primer's answer. But, you should be careful in Python3 because of **dict_keys**. For instance,

```
>> df.loc[df[filter_v.keys()].isin(filter_v.values()).all(axis=1), :]
>> TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict_keys'
```

The correct way to Python3:

```
df.loc[df[list(filter_v.keys())].isin(list(filter_v.values())).all(axis=1), :]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also create a query

```
query_string = ' and '.join(
    [f'({key} == "{val}")' if type(val) == str else f'({key} == {val})' for key, val in filter_v.items()]
)

df1.query(query_string)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way:

```
filterSeries = pd.Series(np.ones(df.shape[0],dtype=bool))
for column, value in filter_v.items():
    filterSeries = ((df[column] == value) & filterSeries)
```

This gives:

```
>>> df[filterSeries]
   A  B      C  D
3  1  0  right  3
```

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on DSM's answer, you can also use `any()` to turn your query into an OR operation (instead of AND):

`df1.loc[(df1[list(filter_v)] == pd.Series(filter_v)).any(axis=1)]`

Answer (score 0):

Combining previous answers, here's a function you can feed to `df1.loc`. Allows for AND/OR (using `how='all'`/`'any'`), plus it allows comparisons other than `==` using the `op` keyword, if desired.

```
import operator

def quick_mask(df, filters, how='all', op=operator.eq) -> pd.Series:
    if how == 'all':
        comb = pd.Series.all
    elif how == 'any':
        comb = pd.Series.any
    return comb(op(df[[*filters]], pd.Series(filters)), axis=1)

# Usage
df1.loc[quick_mask(df1, filter_v)]
```

Answer (score -2):

I had an issue due to my dictionary having multiple values for the same key.

I was able to change DSM's query to:

```
df1.loc[df1[list(filter_v)].isin(filter_v).all(axis=1), :]
```

Comment: @Muhammad thanks for the edit. I'm not yet familiar with the formatting since it was my first post.