# Apply multiple string containment filters to pandas dataframe using dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I need to set a filter on multiple columns based on string containment which will be specified in the dict `column_filters` while ignoring text case using `toupper()` or something along those lines ... for example

```
column_filters = {'COLUMN_1': ['drum', 'gui'], 'COLUMN_2': ['sta', 'kic']}

df = pd.DataFrame({'COLUMN_1': ['DrumSet', 'GUITAR', 'String', 'Bass', 'Violin'],
                   'COLUMN_2': ['STAND', 'DO', 'KICKSET', 'CAT', 'CELLO'],
                   'COLUMN_3': ['LOSER', 'LOVE', 'LICKING', 'STICK', 'BOLOGNA'])
```

DataFrame to filter based On `COLUMN_FILTERS` dict:

```
         COLUMN_1   COLUMN_2    COLUMN_3
      0 DrumSet      STAND       LOSER
      1 GUITAR       DO          LOVE
      2 String       KICKSET     LICKING
      3 Bass         CAT         STICK
      4 Violin       CELLO       BOLOGNA
```

Result:

```
    COLUMN_1    COLUMN_2     COLUMN_3
0   DrumSet      STAND       LOSER
1   GUITAR       DO          LOVE
2   String       KICKSET     LICKING
```

Comment: the code to construct your df, does not match your posted input and result

Comment: fixed the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd convert the dict values into a regex pattern by joining all strings with `'|'`, you can then use `str.contains` to filter the df:

```
In [50]:
for k in column_filters.keys():
    column_filters[k] = '|'.join(column_filters[k])
column_filters

Out[50]:
{'COLUMN_1': 'drum|gui', 'COLUMN_2': 'sta|kic'}
```

now filter using using `str.contains` with param `case=False`:

```
In [51]:
df.loc[(df['COLUMN_1'].str.contains(column_filters['COLUMN_1'], case=False)) | (df['COLUMN_2'].str.contains(column_filters['COLUMN_2'], case=False))]

Out[51]:
  COLUMN_1 COLUMN_2
0  DrumSet    STAND
1   GUITAR       DO
2   String  KICKSET
```

**Update**

OK there is a dynamic method:

```
In [68]:
df[df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('|'.join(column_filters[x.name]), case=False)).any(axis=1)]

Out[68]:
  COLUMN_1 COLUMN_2
0  DrumSet    STAND
1   GUITAR       DO
2   String  KICKSET
```

We can see without the boolean masking that it correctly matches:

```
In [69]:
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('|'.join(column_filters[x.name]), case=False))

Out[69]:
  COLUMN_1 COLUMN_2
0     True     True
1     True    False
2    False     True
3    False    False
4    False    False
```

**Update 2**

To answer you modified question again:

```
In [75]:
df[df[list(column_filters.keys())].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('|'.join(column_filters[x.name]), case=False)).any(axis=1)]

Out[75]:
  COLUMN_1 COLUMN_2 COLUMN_3
0  DrumSet    STAND    LOSER
1   GUITAR       DO     LOVE
2   String  KICKSET  LICKING
```

Comment: the column selection could range from 1 - 5 different columns to select from.. is there a way to consolidate the filter statement as in this post?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34157811/filter-a-pandas-dataframe-using-values-from-a-dict

Comment: no because you're looking for partial matching, that solution is looking for exact matches, what you could to do is stack the df and do a single comparison, I'll post an update

Comment: Actually although it may work it isn't semantically correct to stack and compare as you're looking for specific column comparison, if we stacked the df to make a single column and looked for partial matching then you'd get false-positives, for instance COLUMN_1 contains STAND or KICKSET would return True

Comment: I could do if statements with your solution above and raise `ValueError` when more than five columns passed which would be excessive to begin with.

Comment: Actually there is a neater way to do this, see my update, this will handle a dynamic number of columns, so long as the dict key values match your df column names exactly

Comment: if there are additional columns in the dataframe this will not work.  It throws - see update above. 

KeyError: ('COLUMN_3', 'occurred at index COLUMN_3')

Comment: If you don't define your problem domain initially then the answer will never satisfy your expanding domain. I can only answer what is posted. It's trivial to handle these kind of situations and I clearly stated that the column names and dict keys must match