# Filtering a Dataframe using dictionary with multiple elements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I've tried for a few hours now to find an answer here but I am unable to get any to work in my particular case. Closest I could find was this: [Apply multiple string containment filters to pandas dataframe using dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43389163/apply-multiple-string-containment-filters-to-pandas-dataframe-using-dictionary)

I have a pd.Dataframe of deal prices with the following columns:

```
df1 = database[['DealID',
         'Price',
         'Attribute A',
         'Attribute B',
         'Attribute C']]
```

The attributes are categorised into the following:

```
filter_options = {
    'Attribute A': ["A1","A2","A3","A4"],
    'Attribute B': ["B1","B2","B3","B4"],
    'Attribute C': ["C1","C2","C3"],
}
```

I want to filter df1 using a subset of `filter_options` which has ***multiple*** values per key:

```
filter = {
    'Attribute A': ["A1","A2"],
    'Attribute B': ["B1"],
    'Attribute C': ["C1","C3"],
}
```

The below works fine when there is only one value per key in the dictionary.

```
df_filtered = df1.loc[(df1[list(filter)] == pd.Series(filter)).all(axis=1)]
```

However, am i able to get the same outcome with multple values per key?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add sample data ?

Comment: Have you looked at this question/answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065885/filter-dataframe-rows-if-value-in-column-is-in-a-set-list-of-values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need change variable `filter` because python reserved word and then use `list comprehension` with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) and [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) for boolean mask:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Attribute A':["A1","A2"],
                    'Attribute B':["B1","B2"],
                    'Attribute C':["C1","C2"],
                    'Price':[140,250]})

filt = {
    'Attribute A': ["A1","A2"],
    'Attribute B': ["B1"],
    'Attribute C': ["C1","C3"],
}

print (df1[list(filt)])
  Attribute A Attribute B Attribute C
0          A1          B1          C1
1          A2          B2          C2

mask = pd.concat([df1[k].isin(v) for k, v in filt.items()], axis=1).all(axis=1)
print (mask)
0     True
1    False
dtype: bool

df_filtered = df1[mask]
print (df_filtered)
  Attribute A Attribute B Attribute C  Price
0          A1          B1          C1    140
```