# Python - Filter DataFrame by flexible length dict

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I got a DataFrame like this:

```
    A  B  C
1   1  3  5
2   1  3  6
3   2  4  7
4   2  4  8
```

I know I can filter fixed column as below:

```
df[df[A]==1 & df[B]==3]
```

> But if I want to filter the DataFrame by flexible length of dict:
>
> ```
> dict = {'A':1, 'B':3, 'C':5]}
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> dict = {'A':2, 'B':4}
> ```

And I can get:

> ```
>     A  B  C 
> 1   1  3  5
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
>     A  B  C
> 3   2  4  7
> 4   2  4  8
> ```

How can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: I think you need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34157811/2901002)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your dictionary has its values in a list then you can pass it to the DataFrame `isin` method.

```
d = {'A':[1], 'B':[3], 'C':[5]}
df[df.isin(d)[list(d.keys())].all(axis=1)]

   A  B  C
1  1  3  5
```

If you have lots of items in your dictionary, you can automate the conversion of the values into one item lists like this.

```
{k:[v] for k,v in d.items()}
```