# Filtering pandas dataframe using dictionary for column values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, filter

### Premise

I need to use a dictionary as a filter on a large dataframe, where the key-value pairs are values in different columns.
This dictionary is obtained from a separate dataframe, using `dict(zip(df.id_col, df.rank_col))` so if a dictionary isn't the best way to go, that is open to change.

This is very similar to this question: [Filter a pandas dataframe using values from a dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34157811/filter-a-pandas-dataframe-using-values-from-a-dict) but fundamentally (I think) different because my dictionary contains column-paired values:

### Example data

```
df_x = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3], 
'B':[1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1], 'Rank':['1','2','3','1', '2','3','1','2','3'],'D':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]})
filter_dict = {'1':'1', '2':'3', '3':'2'}
```

For this dataframe `df_x` I would want to be able to look at the filter dictionary and apply it to a set of columns, here `id` and `Rank`, so the dataframe is pared down to:

[image]

The actual source dataframe is approx 1M rows, and the dictionary is >100 key-value pairs.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check with `isin`

```
df_x[df_x[['id','Rank']].astype(str).apply(tuple,1).isin(filter_dict.items())]
Out[182]: 
   id  B Rank  D
0   1  1    1  1
5   2  0    3  6
7   3  0    2  8
```

Comment: This didn't work, as both columns are int64; was easy to change to `astype(int)` though! Thanks (again) W-B!!