# how to write function to dynamically query pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a pandas dataframe from which I will need to repeatedly query a subset of rows. I'd like to wrap this in a function. The queries will vary, interrogating any number of columns. The operator for each column will always be the same. I'm considering something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': list('aabbccddeeff'), 'B': list('aaaabbbbcccc'),
                   'C': np.random.randint(5, size=12),
                   'D': np.random.randint(9, size=12)})

def query_df(df, **kwds):
    a_val = kwds.get('a', None)
    b_val = kwds.get('b', None)
    c_val = kwds.get('c', None)        
    d_val = kwds.get('d', None)
    query = 'A in {0} and B == {1} and C > {2} and D < {3}'.format(a_val, b_val, c_val, d_val)
    return df.query(query)

query_dict = {'a':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'b':'a', 'c':0, 'd':8}
print(query_df(df, **query_dict))

A  B  C  D 
1  a  a  1  6
```

Although this works, it doesn't allow queries directed to e.g. just columns A and C. All columns are hard-coded into the query string! How can I make this more flexible so that e.g. the following would also work:

```
query_df(df, {'a':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'b':'a'})
query_df(df, {'b':'a', 'c':6})
query_df(df, {'d':4})
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might find this helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34157811/filter-a-pandas-dataframe-using-values-from-a-dict

Comment: That's indeed interesting and I hadn't seen those yet. However, it's not a clean a solution as I'd hoped. Wouldn't there exists a keyword instead of 'None' that I can slot into the query and lets pass all values in the respective column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give you an idea how this can be achieved:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': list('aabbccddeeff'), 'B': list('aaaabbbbcccc'),
                   'C': np.random.randint(5, size=12),
                   'D': np.random.randint(9, size=12)})
print(df)
def query_df(df, dicti):
    d = {
      'a' : 'A in %s' % dicti.get('a'),
      'b' : 'B == %s' % dicti.get('b'),
      'c' : 'C > %s' % dicti.get('c') ,
      'd' : 'D < %s' % dicti.get('d')
    }
    q = []
    for i, j in d.items():
      if i in dicti.keys():
        q.append(j)
        q.append(' and ')
    q = q[:len(q)-1]
    query = ''.join(q)
    print(query)
    return df.query(query)
#di = {'a':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'b':'"a"', 'c':0, 'd':8}
#di = {'b':'"a"', 'c':6}
#di = {'d':4}
di = {'a':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'b':'"a"'}
print(query_df(df, di))
```

I had to use double quotes for 'b' key ('b':'"a"') as you might notice.