# How do I extract the rows of a DataFrame based on the value of a row that acts as a key to a dictionary?

Tags: pandas

To elaborate on the title, I have a DataFrame with a column called `CATEGORY`. Let's say that this category contains various types of produce and takes the values of `['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'carrot', 'potato', ...]`.

I want to extract rows where the value of `CATEGORY` is a fruit and not a vegetable. I also have a dictionary that maps each row value to its larger category:

```
produce2category = {'apple': 'fruit',
                    'banana': 'fruit',
                    'carrot': 'vegetable',
                    ...}
```

I want to extract all rows of the larger DataFrame without using the current for loop approach that I have:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> fruit_dict = {'apple': 'fruit', 'banana': 'fruit', 'carrot': 'vegetable', 'potato': 'vegetable'}
>>> rows = [['apple', 1, 2, 3], ['potato', 4, 5, 6], ['banana', 7, 8, 9], ['carrot', 10, 11, 12]]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['CATEGORY', '1', '2', '3'])
>>> fruit_rows = []
>>> for idx, row in df.iterrows():
...     if fruit_dict[row['CATEGORY']] == 'fruit':
...         fruit_rows.append(row)
...
>>> fruit_df = pd.DataFrame(fruit_rows)
```

I've tried `df.loc[fruit_dict[df['CATEGORY']] == 'fruit']` but get a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'` error.

I've also taken a look at [this Stack Overflow question (Filter a pandas dataframe using values from a dict)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34157811/filter-a-pandas-dataframe-using-values-from-a-dict) but it seems to address something a little different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
out = df[df['CATEGORY'].map(produce2category).eq('fruit')]
```

Or pre-filter the fruits and use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
out = df[df['CATEGORY'].isin({k for k,v in produce2category.items() if v == 'fruit'})]
```

Output:

```
  CATEGORY  1  2  3
0    apple  1  2  3
2   banana  7  8  9
```