# Efficiently finding values in pandas dataframe filtering by different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm doing some work with a pandas dataframe, and I need to filter the data according to different columns. This is easily done with pandas syntax, as shown in the Minimal Working Example below:

```py
import pandas as pd

#Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['one','two','three','four', 'five'],'col2':[1,2,3,4,5],'col3':[0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7], 'col4':[0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8]})
print(df)
#Filter wanted values
print(df[(df['col1'] == 'one') & (df['col2'] == 1)])
```

The problem is, when the number of columns you have to filter by is large (more than 4), this syntax rapidly becomes a really long chain of `&` and `|` with a lot of redundant elements on it, and it's really hard to read afterwards. I'll leave an example of that happening here: `data_raw[(data_raw['Metales'] == 'MoO3') | (data_raw['Metales_0'] == 'MoO3') | (data_raw['Metales_1'] == 'MoO3')| (data_raw['Metales_2'] == 'MoO3')]`
(this is just to ilustrate how fast it becomes too long to read comfortably, in theory, I won't be needing to check the same column for 2 different values)

Is there a more pythonic and clean way to select values in a bunch of different columns?

Comment: You can simplify the last example with [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html). It works well when you provide a filter that you can reuse.

Comment: Does this approach help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34157811/filter-a-pandas-dataframe-using-values-from-a-dict

Comment: It does, in fact, it basically solves the problem I was trying to solve, thanks, @s_pike

Comment: so, it's a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/34157811/12846804, after all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34157811/filter-a-pandas-dataframe-using-values-from-a-dict) provided by [@s_pike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13258525/s-pike?tab=profile), I was able to find one easy way of searching through the dataframe checking different columns at a time.

```py
import pandas as pd

#Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['one','two','three','four', 'five'],'col2':[1,2,3,4,5],'col3':[0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7], 'col4':[0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8]})
print(df)

#Create a dictionary with the column names as keys and the wanted values as values
filterv = {'col1': 'one', 'col2': 1, 'col3': 0.3, 'col4': 0.4}

#Filter de dataframe according to the values
print(df.loc[(df[list(filterv)] == pd.Series(filterv)).all(axis=1)])
```

What we're doing is:

```
1. Creating a dictionary `filterv` where the column names are the keys and the desired values are the values
2. Creating a `pd.Series` out of that dictionary
3. Selecting the corresponding columns of the df with df[list(filterv)]
4. Comparing the columns of the df with the series we created.
```

In any case [the other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34157811/filter-a-pandas-dataframe-using-values-from-a-dict) has it explained line by line

Comment: It's a pity you really got us side-tracked with your example. Which was about 3 columns fitting one identical pair of values, while in fact you were looking for  a number of columns, each satisfying a different equality.

Comment: Yeah, maybe it wasn't the best example, sorry

Comment: But anyway, I had another different problem right now and came back to this question because I remembered the isin method, so it did serve me well!!

Answer (score 4):

You could consider using [query](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)

```
print(df.query("col1 == 'one' and col2 == 1"))
```

In your other example, it would look something along these lines:

```
data_raw.query("Metales in ['MoO3', 'MoO2'] or Metales_0 in ['MoO3', 'MoO2'] or Metales_1 in ['MoO3', 'MoO2']")
```

Comment: This helps with readability, but not with lenght.

Comment: The second example is actually about half the number of characters.

Comment: Yeah, but taking into account that I won't need to check for more than one value (at least in theory), It's not as useful, as it still gets really long really fast

Answer (score 2):

My first idea was in agreement with rochard4du's comment.

```py
df[  df['col1'].isin(['one','two']) 
   | df['col2'].isin([1    ,2]) 
   | df['col3'].isin([0.3  ,0.4])]
```

Both `.isin()` and `query()` methods help with length, by decreasing number of tests 2-fold, in your molybden oxide example.

Arne was onto something, only missing to include columns selection:

```
df[df[['col1','col2']].isin(['one', 'two']).any(axis=1)]
```

Applied to your example:

```py
tested_columns  = ['Metales', 'Metales_0', 'Metales_1']
accepted values = ['MoO2','MoO3']

data_raw[dataraw[tested_columns].isin(accepted_values).any(axis=1)]
```

Now if you were checking against a single value instead of a list, just reduce the list to that value. Replacing `.isin` with `==` is not that straightforward.

Comment: I'm just trying to check versus single values, there shouldn't be cases where isin would be useful, although I agree they help with lenght and readability

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the `isin` suggestion by rochard4u, if the values you are looking for repeat across columns, NumPy methods like [any](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) may be useful. For example, your last expression could be written as:

```py
data_raw[data_raw.isin(['MoO2', 'MoO3']).any(axis=1)]
```